# Highlight object that was just edited in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I have an UpdateView in which I edit a single object. When the form is valid I am redirecting the user to a list with many objects.

In this list I want to highlight the object that was just successfully edited. I know Django's message framework where I can transfer messages from a view to another but how can I send which id to highlight?

Answer (score 0):

Messages aren't really the right solution. Instead, use the sessions framework.

```
# in editing view:
obj = data.save() # or whatever
request.session['edited_object_id'] = obj.id
return ....


# in list view:
highlighted_id = request.session['edited_object_id']
# and in template:
{% for obj in objects %}
    <li class="{% if obj.id == highlighted_id %}">...</li>
{% endif %}
```